# Getting SSLCertVerificationError, but CURL is working

Tags: python, ssl, aiohttp

I'm trying to replicate a CURL command using aiohttp in Python.

```bash
curl -k -X POST https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com  \
    --cert file.cer:pass \
    --key file.key \
    -u "XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -d "username=XXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -d "password=XXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

That works fine.

Reading the docs here, https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets, I create a SSL Context like so, using Python's ssl module:

```py
import ssl

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()

ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
    certfile=CERT_PATH,
    keyfile=KEY_PATH,
    password=KEY_PASS
)
```

Then, with aiohttp when executing a request:

```py
async with session.post(url,json=body,ssl=ssl_context) as r:
    ...
```

And I get this:

```bash
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: this seems like a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: this article also may be useful https://rob-blackbourn.medium.com/secure-communication-with-python-ssl-certificate-and-asyncio-939ae53ccd35

Comment: I just skimmed over [some Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#context-creation). Does anything change if you change `ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()` to `ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)`?

Comment: @MichaelM. `Purpose.SERVER_AUTH` is the default attribute, so that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

Solved this by following the answer here: [How can I create a Python SSL Client/Server pair where only the server authenticates the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980192/how-can-i-create-a-python-ssl-client-server-pair-where-only-the-server-authentic)

Basically replaced `ssl.create_default_context()` with `ssl.SSLContext()`

Only thing is that now I get a warning:

```bash
DeprecationWarning: ssl.SSLContext() without protocol argument is deprecated.
DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS is deprecated
```

But that is a problem for another day. I'm open to hear more suggestions, *tho*.